# Editing a text file in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this in a text file :

```
Rubble HM3 80 HM2 90 HM4 92

Bunny HM2 92 HM5 70 HM1 98

Duck HM1 86 HM3 100 HM2 93 HM4 94

Chipmunk HM4 96 HM1 86

Simpson HM3 70 HM1 90 Test1  90
```

and i want to write a code that changes it to this :

```
Name            | HM1 | HM2 | HM3 | HM4 | Avg. |
________________________________________________
Bunny           |  98 |  92 |   0 |   0 | 47.50 |

Chipmunk        |  86 |   0 |   0 |  96 | 45.50 |

Duck            |  86 |  93 | 100 |  94 | 93.25 |

Rubble          |   0 |  90 |  80 |  92 | 65.50 |

Simpson         |  90 |   0 |  70 |   0 | 40.00 |
```

so far :

```
my_file=open("C:/python27/tools/student_grades.txt", "r+")

my_file_pointer=my_file.read()

for lines in my_file_pointer:

        x=my_file_pointer.replace("HM2","|")

print x
```

Go Easy first time programmer . :)

and if i use the replace function how can i print it all at once and then sort it under every subject "HM1" ?

Comment: Is it homework? Do you need to do it with basic python or can you use external modules? I don;t think replace is serving any purpose here. What do you intend to do with it? In any case, I think it will be better if you think and try a little more. Hint: You can load the values into a `dict` first.

Comment: yeah, but i have this professor who kinda dosent explain anything so i depend on external info, i thought i could do it with list functions with name.readlines() but i've been looking for hours for list functions but didn't find anything

Comment: You'll want to read up on lists: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists and dictionaries: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries - that should help you think with how to approach the problem.

Comment: okay so after i use dict([('HM1', 92) , if someone enters different numbers in the text?